# System Resources Exceeded whilst performing UPDATE SQL in Access inside Transaction

Tags: vba, transactions, ms-access-2010

I'm performing a simple `UPDATE tblTable SET DataSet=3` inside a transaction, but a few seconds after trying to run it, I get a 3035 - System Resources exceeded.  There are ~30K rows.

```
Dim db As DAO.Database, wrk As DAO.Workspace, errCount As Long, stSQL As String

Set db = CurrentDb
Set wrk = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
errCount = 0
wrk.BeginTrans
    Debug.Print "There are no existing entries in the selected DataSet, preparing to proceed..."
    ' - -- ---
    stSQL = "UPDATE tblImportCleaned SET DataSetID=" & Me.lstDataSets
    db.Execute stSQL, dbSeeChanges
    If db.RecordsAffected < 1 Then errCount = errCount + 1
    Me.frmImport_CleanedSubform.Requery
    ' - -- ---

If errCount = 0 Then
    If MsgBox("There were no errors, would you like to COMMIT the changes?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        wrk.CommitTrans
    Else
        wrk.Rollback
    End If
Else
    wrk.Rollback
End If
wrk.Close
```

Any idea why this is happening and how I can avoid it please.

Comment: Are the tables MS Access or linked from another DB?

Comment: If it is MS Access, it is because of the Transactions, but I do not know how to avoid the problem but keep the transactions.

Comment: Yeah, they are MS Access tables.

Comment: There is a post somewhere that I cannot remember properly, if you are updating, Access requires double the space (number of records) for the period of the update. I suspect you may be going over a record limit, but I can't find the details at the moment.

Comment: I'll have a peruse through other posts, let me know if you work it out please ;)

Comment: I did see a post about forcing acccess to use the same connection, rather than opening a new connection per record or something along those lines, will have a look at that...

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be you are updating entire table i.e without where condition, are you sure you want to update entire table and if you are updating entire table in a loop (i don't see loop in you code, still you may be calling this procedure in a loop) system has high possibility of getting this error.

Comment: Yes, I wish to update entire table and no it is not in a loop.