# system resources exceeded when performing INSERTwith JOIN in transaction

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, dao

I have a transaction that changes some records in a parent table and then calls a function to update child tables: Change the foreign key and save the primary key and old foreign key in an Audit table.

The code ran well without problems when there where 8 child tables, but then I added another child table to be updated, and after the code runs for some time I get the following error when trying an Insert Into audit:

> System resources exceeded

If I click debug and wait a few seconds, then step into the code, it seems to proceed, I don't get an error when trying the insert, but it doesn't actually insert the correct record.

```vb
Set myWorkSpace = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
myWorkSpace.BeginTrans

'do some update queries'

Call UpdateChildTables("MasterTable", 1080651)
myWorkSpace.CommitTrans

Public Sub UpdateChildTables(ByVal tableName As String, ByVal masterId As String)
Set rsChildTables = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("childTables")
ReDim Preserve arrChildTables(4, 1)
rsChildTables .MoveFirst
i = 0

Do While Not rsChildTables .EOF
    arrChildTables(0, i) = rsChildTables .Fields(0)'the id in childTables tbl'
    arrChildTables(1, i) = rsChildTables .Fields(1)'name of the child tbl'
    arrChildTables(2, i) = rsChildTables .Fields(2)'name of PK field in child tbl'
    arrChildTables(3, i) = rsChildTables .Fields(3)'name of FK field in child tbl'
    ReDim Preserve arrChildTables(4, UBound(arrChildTables, 2) + 1)
    i = i + 1
    rsChildTables .MoveNext
Loop
rsChildTables .Close
Set rsChildTables = Nothing

j = i
DoCmd.SetWarnings False

For i = 0 To j - 1
    'insert into the audit tbl the id in childTables tbl, the primary key, and the foreign key'
    'before the foreign key gets updated'
    strSql = "INSERT INTO audit ( ChildTablesId, primaryKey, ForeignKey) SELECT " & arrChildTables(0, i) & ", " & arrChildTables(1, i) & "." & arrChildTables(2, i) & ", " & arrChildTables(1, i) & "." & arrChildTables(3, i) & " FROM " & arrChildTables(1, i) & " INNER JOIN track on " & arrPending(1, i) & "." & arrChildTables(3, i) & " = track.sub WHERE track.super = " & masterId
    DoCmd.RunSQL strSql
    strSql = "UPDATE " & arrChildTables(1, i) & " INNER JOIN Track ON " & arrChildTables(1, i) & "." & arrChildTables(3, i) & " = Track.sub Set " & arrChildTables(1, i) & "." & arrChildTables(3, i) & " = Track.super WHERE track" & tableName & ".master =" & masterId
    DoCmd.RunSQL strSql
Next i
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Sub
```

[image]

Basically, my code identifies sub companies in the master table (**Companies**), and updates the foreign key in child tables (**Employees**) to the super company's id.

Table **Track** identifies the super and sub. I update some fields in the super company in the master table, then update all child tables that are listed in **childTables** table.

I backup the previous foreign key for each record in the child tables, in **audit** table.

The insert is slecting only one record. I tried searchin online but all answer were for OleDb or unclear.

[image]

Comment: DBEngine.SetOption dbMaxLocksPerFile, 100000

Comment: Is the `myWorkSpace.BeginTrans` in there to ensure data integrity, or to improve performance? If the latter, try adding a `CommitTrans` plus `BeginTrans` after each SQL execution. This should reduce the needed resources (for rollback).

Comment: How many child tables do you maintain? Hundreds? Personally, I would save every insert/update query into a stored query object with passed in parameters if needed. Then call them, even in loop: `DoCmd.OpenQuery` This helps organization and Access compiles, optimizes, and saves the query plan instead of this dynamic looped VBA concatenation. You can even create such queries initially in VBA if they are in the hundreds.

Comment: @parfait, I don't know how many child tables will be every time I need to run this code, but there definitely won't be hundreds. Maybe 20, maximum. Will saving the query help with my problem?

Comment: @Andre, the transaction is there to insure data integrity.

Comment: @VolleyballAddictSandiego, Is it completely safe to do that? I'm currently running code on my private DB, but once it works, I will have to run it on the company's system.

Comment: Related, but no solution either: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218256/system-resources-exceeded-whilst-performing-update-sql-in-access-inside-transact -- This may be difficult/impossible to solve without changing your approach.

Comment: Regarding `dbMaxLocksPerFile`: I'd say it's safe to try (though you should make a copy of your production DB before running it there), but I think it is geared toward a different error: [Run-time error '3052': File sharing lock count exceeded. Increase MaxLocksPerFile registry entry.](http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=1997910)

Comment: @Is there no way so add like `commit` or something if I receive that error and continue the transaction? or pause?

Comment: Most of my ACCDB complex VBA projects won't work without the dbMaxLocks option. It may help your issue or it may not, which is why this is a Comment not an Answer.

Comment: @Andre, dbMaxLocksPerFile seems to work. How do I reset it after running the code?

Comment: The forum thread I linked has info about that, the default value seems to be **9500**. @VolleyballAddictSandiego: it appears I was wrong. Sorry :)

Comment: worked huh?  ok good!  should I re-enter it as an Answer so you can give me credit for it?  LOL